# Can't run Bitcoin Core 0.13.1

Tags: bitcoin-core, linux, ubuntu

I have been running Bitcoin Core 0.12.1 for many months - using Ubuntu (Linux).  Decided to upgrade to SegWit version - 0.13.1 - today.  Downloaded and extracted the files (on my Ubuntu / Linux system) but can't get it to run - there is no executable file.  Can anyone help?  Many thanks, D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the ppa for ubuntu is https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/ubuntu/bitcoin it shows the support of ubuntu 0.13.1

so you need to run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
```

[image]
otherwise you can compile from source

Comment: Many thanks - very grateful for the trouble you have gone to to reply.

Comment: Have done all that - still no bitcoin client (if that is what it is called) - i.e. no bitcoin core wallet appears

Comment: did you installed bitcoind and bitcoin-qt using sudo apt-get install bitcoin-qt? the gui wallet is runned using bitcoin-qt

Comment: That did the trick - many thanks - I really am most grateful for your help.  By the way, can you recommend a book on Linux terminal commands for a beginner like me?

Comment: I have accepted it - many thanks once again - you have been a great help.